# How to pack Reason and Ktor apps together in a bundle with Gradle?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, reason, ktor

I have the following structure:

```
/             -> root
/react-app    -> Reason app (initialized using cli)
/webapp       -> gradle app, maven structure with Gradle build file
```

I am not sure how to build everything so I can:

1. run server locally so I can debug
2. make production tar (using the `application` plugin for example)

#### Production

The production should look like this:

- ktor as a main server
- ktor app has API
- all react JS/HTML files are also served by ktor

In other words, I would like to serve everything from single web app.

I am aware that I could make 2 separate services - one for react, one for API. But I want to bundle this together into single app.

#### Local development

Local development should be quick. I was thinking in having separate React and API part for the local purpose only, as that is easier to run locally. But for production I need those two to be served from single app.

#### What I would like to have

is a single Gradle in the root and having modules. While ktor can be a module, I am not sure how to operate with react module.

Comment: This depends on what it means to "make production tar" - how do you intend to serve the React app in production?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Kotlin and Ktor parts, but on the Reason/React side I'd recommend [Parcel](http://parceljs.org/) to bundle your HTML/JS/CSS assets into a form suitable for serving statically, and also use it as a development server for fast iteration.

Parcel requires zero config for most cases and you can point it at your entrypoint asset, usually your `index.html` file in your UI project, and in production builds it will bundle everything (HTML/JS/CSS) inside a `dist/` subdirectory ready to be served. Then just point your Kotlin webapp to serve `dist/index.html` for the `/` route.

For development builds Parcel will automatically start up a development server at `localhost:1234` with auto-reloading. When you're iterating on the UI, the BuckleScript incremental build along with the Parcel reload, should be pretty fast–usually almost instant.